# WordPress: attachment image with different sizes

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

I have a small problem with a custom loop in WordPress. I'm using the royal slider (normal jquery version) and want to display the attached images of a post as a slider.

So far, it works with this code:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ):
                echo '<div class="rsContent">';
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'large', array( 'class' => 'rsImg'));
                $description = $attachment->post_content;
                if ($description):
                    echo '<div class="infoBlock infoBlockLeftBlack rsABlock" data-fade-effect="" data-move-offset="10" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200">';
                    echo $description;
                    echo '</div>';
                endif;
                echo '</div>';
            endforeach;
        }
    ?>
```

So I get the attached images in fullsize. But now I like to get the attached images in medium and thumbnail size, too, so that I can create a responsive slider.

The way would be, that I can do a picture tag like this:

```
<picture>
<source srcset="Attachment Thumbnail size" media="(max-width: 400)">
<source srcset="Attachment Medium size" media="(max-width: 900)">
<source srcset="Attachment Full size">
<img srcset="Attachment Full size">
</picture>
```

Does anybody of you have a quick tip?

Thank you!

Comment: This: `echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'large', array( 'class' => 'rsImg'));` makes no sense, since [wp_get_attachment_url](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) admits only id. I think you confused it with [wp_get_attachment_image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

Comment: oh sorry, yes, that's right. I've played around with wp_get_attachment_url and wp_get_attachment_image and copied the wrong code. 

The code works with wp_get_attachment_image. But I just would need the src argument and everything would be fine :/

Comment: There is a [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src). Have you tried using this?

Answer (score 0):

In place of `large` in  `echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID, 'large', array( 'class' => 'rsImg'));` use `custom-image-size` and define the `custom-image-size` in your functions.php like `add_image_size('custom-image-size',730,280,true);` and then use **regenerate thumbnail** plugin and you will get the image size will be changed to `730*280` , visit codex to know more about this function.

Comment: Hi,
I know about this function. But I have the problem that I don't know how to call the different sizes (best way: just the src attribute) to put together the mentioned picture code. I know how to create a ouput like yimg src="http://www.my-image-url.com/image.jpg" width="xxx" height="xxx" /> for different sizes. But I like to create a picture element with it to create a responsive picture set.

Comment: Have you tried passing array of classes ? I have never done this, but if you want to use different size of images , that is same as creating a lot of images and loading those as it will crop and create another image , so better to find out a way something like using java-script to get the screensize and replace the image class , that can be better solution .